# Ionic v1 : Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, push

Hy, 
I'm using The api to Identify users, register for push notifications and send push notifications to users.
when i send a request to : "https://apps.ionic.io/api/v1/app/d0176479/users/identify" i'm getting : 
the request already : forbidden (403) 
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.
If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for 'same-origin' requests.
any help please !

Comment: Hello Mourad,
It would be great help if you can share the solution if you got the one...!!

Comment: Hello ! I think that it was an ionic server problem :/ it doesn't work anyway, but i found a solution : Onesignal. It works fine ;)

Comment: Thanks for reply, Sir.
It would be great if you can share the solution :D
As I am really stucked in this.

Comment: if u want to use push notifications for ionic, i found another server works fine (www.onesignal.com), it's fast, free and easy to use :D . ionic's push notification server not working for me, i abandon it :/

Comment: Oh... Thanks for the information :)
Then, I will try the link you mentioned and ask you more if required.

Comment: u're welcome :)